# ElementTree text mixed with tags

Tags: python, html, elementtree

imagine the following text:

```
<description>
the thing <b>stuff</b> is very important for various reasons, notably <b>other things</b>.
</description>
```

How would I manage to parse this with the `etree` interface? Having the `description` tag, the `.text` property returns only the first word - `the`. The `.getchildren()` method returns the `<b>` elements, but not the rest of the text.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the `.text_content()`. Working sample using [`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html):

```
from lxml.html import fromstring   

data = """
<description>
the thing <b>stuff</b> is very important for various reasons, notably <b>other things</b>.
</description>
"""

tree = fromstring(data)

print(tree.xpath("//description")[0].text_content().strip())
```

Prints:

```
the thing stuff is very important for various reasons, notably other things.
```

---

> I forgot to specify one thing though, sorry. My ideal parsed version would contain a list of subsections: [normal("the thing"), bold("stuff"), normal("....")], is that possible with the lxml.html library?

Assuming you'll have only text nodes and `b` elements inside a description:

```
for item in tree.xpath("//description/*|//description/text()"):
    print([item.strip(), 'normal'] if isinstance(item, basestring) else [item.text, 'bold'])
```

Prints:

```
['the thing', 'normal']
['stuff', 'bold']
['is very important for various reasons, notably', 'normal']
['other things', 'bold']
['.', 'normal']
```

Comment: I forgot to specify one thing though, sorry. My ideal parsed version would contain a list of subsections: [normal("the thing"), bold("stuff"), normal("....")], is that possible with the `lxml.html` library?